# Background image of opaque navigation bar is rendered incorrectly on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, uiimage, uinavigationbar

When I set background image with method

```
setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:
```

it's rendered like this on iPhone 6

[image: navigation bar on iPhone 6]

If i set the navigation bar to `translucent`, it's stretched normally.
[image]

```
@implementation OHCNavigationBar

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setupGradient];
    }   
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self setupGradient];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setupGradient {
    UIImage *gradientImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackground.png"];
   [self setBackgroundImage:gradientImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `UINavigationBar` background image with non repeat mode by setting edge to 0.

```
UIImage *gradientImage32 = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"bkg_top_header_default.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32
                                   forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:gradientImage32 forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

**Update 1:**

```
- (void)setupGradient {
    UIImage *gradientImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigationBarBackground.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)  resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

    [self setBackgroundImage:gradientImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

May this help you.

Enjoy Coding !!

Comment: @aterite Is this helps you?

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't change. I don't know, should I set other insets?

Comment: Can you post your code to setup background image, so I can help you more batter way.

Comment: Thanks, I added resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch

Comment: Is your problem solved?, if not, then you should try edge inset like UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 160, 0, 160), updated in my answer previously.

Comment: Yes, setting resizingMode to stretch solved issue. can you edit your answer by adding uiimageResizingModeStretch and insets(0,0,0,0) from my previous comment